# Trying to pass Data from current VC to the next but first checking if the user inputs the correct info

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboard, ibaction

I am trying to pass data from the current View Controller to the next View Controller using an IBAction because I also need to check if the user is using the correct User Email and ID before going to the second View Controller. I am still new to Objective-C and Xcode. I thought this would work but it doesn't. It will not pass the number 15 to the second VC. I would like to for it to be something like this. Please help me figure out a way to do this. This is actually for my Final Project that is due today. Lol

```
- (IBAction)signInButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    DatabaseManager *data = [DatabaseManager new]; // A DB Using SQLite3

    if (![self.studentEmailField.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![self.studentMDCID.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

        if ([data checkStudentEmail:self.studentEmailField.text checkStudentID:self.studentMDCID.text]) {

            StudentMainPageViewController *secoundVC = [StudentMainPageViewController new];

            secoundVC.rowInDB = 15;

            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            UIViewController *StudentMainPageVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StudentMainPageID"];

            [self presentViewController:StudentMainPageVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with your code ?

Comment: The 15 will not get passed to the second VC

Comment: if you are using  sqlite, try to use a singleton class!!!

Comment: did u check that data is nill ? and it goes through the loop ?

Comment: Use I have tested that it does in the IF just fine.

Comment: show the code of how you are retriving the value in your second VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use following solution:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) 
    {
        DestinationViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];

        dest.myData = self.myData; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It still wont pass the 15. And I have the correct property in place in the .h of the 2nd VC